# Iron Router pathFor='/' does not work

Tags: meteor

Iron Router pathFor does not work when looking for route '/' or ''.

I'm trying to create a link to homepage here but it does not seem to accept that route. Routing is set properly and works properly by entering it.

Is there a special pathFor for homepages?

Comment: can you show router file and real code of your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the name of the route as the parameter. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know routes can have names. I thought they were only set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if @user3594721 make spacebars

```
{{pathFor "/"}}
```

it is wrong, and check inside Router method. also you don't have route for homepage (or root page), make route for homepage

change

```
{{pathFor "/"}}
```

to

```
{{pathFor "something you typed name of homepage"}}
```